# Specification of the parameters of this utility function [Behavioral Economics]

Tags: utility, behavioral-economics, fairness

[image]This is from page 274 of "Advances in Behavioural Economics" by Camerer, Rabin, Loewenstein.
This chapter of the book is entitled "A theory about fairness, competition, and cooperation".

I have difficulty understanding parts of this equation. (see attachment).
I would need an explanation of the equation in detail (I assume this book is designed for graduate students, as I am currently an undergrad).
What do alpha and beta represent? What does monetary payoff mean exactly? Is it similar to game theory? Why is there a 0 in [*xj-xi, 0*]? And why is it 1/(n-1) and not n-1? This is very confusing for me, who has little mathematical background.

Comment: $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are coefficients related to how much an individual $i$ feels bad about being less wealthy or more wealthy than other people.  $\max\{x_j-x_i,0\}$ is the difference between person $j$'s wealth and person $i$'s wealth if  person $j$'s wealth is higher than person $i$'s wealth; otherwise it is $0$.  The division by $n-1$ to get an average is because there are $n-1$ individuals apart from person $i$ for person $i$ to compare to.

Comment: @Henry: Your comment is actually an answer, and a correct one. Why don't you make it an answer? (Sorry, just curious.)

Comment: @VARulle because sometimes I feel like commenting.  You can use for an answer if you wish

Comment: @Henry: Thx for the offer, but I don't want to adorn myself with borrowed plumes.

Answer (score 1):

As @Henry commented and according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins I made a community wiki with the answer:

> αi and βi are coefficients related to how much an individual i feels bad about being less wealthy or more wealthy than other people. max{xj−xi,0} is the difference between person j's wealth and person i's wealth if person j's wealth is higher than person i's wealth; otherwise it is 0. The division by n−1 to get an average is because there are n−1 individuals apart from person i for person i to compare to.